# Why CreateWindowEx will add WS_CAPTION by default?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create an window by [CreateWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx), but seams even I give both `dwExStyle` `dwStyle` value 0, the window still have `WS_CAPTION` style.

Code snippet as following:

```
   _hWnd = CreateWindowExW(iExStyle, pszClassName, pszTitle, iStyle | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, dX, dY, dWidth, dHeight,
                            hWndParent, 0, hInstance, NULL); 
   ASSERT(GetWindowLong(_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_CAPTION == 0); //<---- This will failed.
```

Comment: A [mcve] would help. We don't know what values you are passing here. Perhaps `iStyle` is `WS_CAPTION`.

Comment: 0 is special, means "use default styles".  That somewhat made sense 32 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dwStyle = 0x00000000L` means `WS_OVERLAPPED or WS_TILED`, this window has a title bar and a border.

[Window Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As emax says, `WS_OVERLAPPED` (0) is the default and results in:

> The window is an overlapped window. An overlapped window has a title bar and a border. Same as the WS_TILED style.

If you are creating a child window you must specify `WS_CHILD` and if you are creating a "popup" window you must use `WS_POPUP` or `WS_POPUPWINDOW`.

A tooltip for example would use `WS_POPUP` and `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` + `WS_EX_TOPMOST`...